# Adjust distance between horizontal legend and plot title ggplotly

Tags: r, charts, legend, title, ggplotly

I have created the following plot in ggplot

```
  library(ggplot2)
  library(plotly)
```

Dataframe is created below

```
 DF<-data.frame("Sl_no"=1:30)
 DF$Name<-c("A", "B")
```

Next We create the plot using ggplot and plotly

```
    plot1<-ggplot(data = DF,mapping =aes(x = Sl_no, y = Sl_no, fill= Name))+theme_bw()+scale_fill_manual("Legend", values = c("A" = "red", "B" = "blue")) + theme(legend.position="top")+geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")+geom_text(aes(label=paste0(Sl_no)),vjust = 1, position = position_dodge(0.5),check_overlap = TRUE)+labs(x = "\nCount", y= "\nFrequency") +labs(title= 'Title_Chart' )+ theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"),axis.title.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"),plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 2)) 


    plot1<-ggplotly(plot1,  dynamicTicks = T) %>% layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", y = 1.1, 
     x=0.5))
      plot1
```

In this chart, the chart title overlaps the horizontal legend. Is it possible to adjust the position of the chart title so that it moves away from the legend while maintaining the current position of the legend. I request someone to guide me here

Comment: having the same issue

Comment: One solution is to adjust the legend y axis. as follows. But it will bring the legend inside the plot

Comment: plot1<-ggplotly(plot1,  dynamicTicks = T) %>% layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", y = 0.99, 
                                                                   x=0.5))
plot1